# Creating a new "internal" process?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, ipc

I'm writing a DLL (in Visual C++) and I recently decided that I need to move stuff that currently happens in threads into their own process. This is because I want to support multiple instances of the DLL being loaded and running. However, they all need to access the same group of resources (i/o buffers to a COM port) that needs to be autonomously monitored as long as there is at least one instance of the DLL running.

It seems I need to use CreateProcess(), but I'm unclear on how I should use the lpApplicationName argument. In the examples I've seen, the name of an existing program gets passed, but that isn't what I imagine I need to do. I expected to be able to start a process by specifying a function, much like with CreateThread(). The process doesn't need to be compiled and output as its own executable, does it? It definitely shouldn't be used by anything other than my DLL. Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, so if all CreateProcess() can do is start a pre-existing program, how can I get this to work? If the following happens:

1. Process loads the DLL
2. DLL starts port monitoring threads
3. Second process loads the DLL
4. Second DLL establishes some IPC to access the same data as the first DLL
5. First DLL is about to exit, and terminates the monitoring threads
6. Second DLL starts its own monitoring threads and continues

Doing 5 and 6 seems (especially with my implementation) like a clunky way of doing things, rather than just have behavior that I never have to terminate and restart.

EDIT: The more I think about this, the more I like the idea of making a separate executable, but if anyone think of a more "elegant" method, I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. On *nix you could `fork` can then call whatever function you want, but `CreateProcess` doesn't work that way. The only thing `CreateProcess` can do is launch a new process with execution starting at the entry point of an **on-disk executable**.